# Upload build artifacts that have changed using GitHub actions

Tags: c#, .net-core, yaml, github-actions

I am trying to establish a GitHub workflow with the help of GitHub Actions. Theoretically, the workflow would deploy any *new* changes to the web server each time a pull request is merged into the master branch.

This is my yaml file thus far:

```
name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.x
      
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore src/my.Web.sln
      
    - name: Build application
      run: dotnet build src/my.Web.sln --no-restore
      
    - name: Test application
      run: dotnet test src/my.Web.sln --no-restore --verbosity normal
      
    - name: Publish artifacts to default path
      run: dotnet publish src/my.Web.sln
      
    - name: Upload build artifacts for deployment
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: Application
        path: /home/runner/work/my-website/my-website/src/my.Web/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish/
```

I can download the artifacts after each merge fine, but *all* the .dll files are uploaded even though I only want the ones that were updated in the most recent push.

Stack Overflow answers on other questions suggested adding `fetch-depth: 0` under the `actions/checkout@v2` step to get only the latest push, but all the files of the application are still uploaded.